# find and compare and count matching of pattern in each column in datarame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

my input:

```
df <- data.frame("Foo"=c("a","c","NG-c","d","e","f"), "Bar"=c("b","b","c","d","e","f"), "Baz" = c("a","a","c","NG-c","NG-c","d")
                 "Gaz" = c("NG-c","NG-c","NG-c", "NG-a","NG-a","NG-a"))
patern <- c("a","c")
```

A problem look a little bit complicated. I trying **find&count&compare** by pattern each column in dataframe. For example - I want find all matching `NG-c` and output in which column the biggest percentage of `NG-c` from total in each column.
That my code:

```
bg <- c()
for (i in ncol(df)) {
  for (pt in length(patern)) {
    tot <- sum(str_count(df[i],patern[pt]))
    ng <- sum(str_count(df[i],paste0("NG-",patern[pt] )))
    res <- round((ng/tot*100),1)
    bg <- c(bg,res) 
                              }
    if (bg[pt] >= res) {  
      print(colnames(df[i])) 
                        }    
                      }
```

So I expect see `Baz` and `Gaz` column name, but I have some troubles.
First I get warning messages:

> Error in if (bg[pt] >= res) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

And second:

> Warning messages: 1: In stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex =
> opts(pattern)) :   argument is not an atomic vector; coercing 2: In
> stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
> argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Perhaps there is a better/clever way?

Comment: The data shared does not work and returns an error. I think you are missing a comma (`,`). Can you show the expected output for this data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your are looking for and how your question text is related to the `patern` vector. If you want to count the occurences of `NG-c` per column and calculate the percantage of `NG-c`s per column, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),
                   ~sum(str_count(.x, "NG-c"))/n()))
```

This returns

```r
        Foo Bar       Baz Gaz
1 0.1666667   0 0.3333333 0.5
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Foo = c("a", "c", "NG-c", "d", "e", "f"), Bar = c("b", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), Baz = c("a", "a", "c", "NG-c", "NG-c", 
"d"), Gaz = c("NG-c", "NG-c", "NG-c", "NG-a", "NG-a", "NG-a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```